# Question about Existential Generalization

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm studying first-order logic with Hilbert proof system (I'm completely new to this) and I need to proof one of the basic identities: $ \neg (\forall x) \neg \phi \implies (\exists x) \phi $

This is what I made:

$ A1: \neg[(\forall x) \neg \phi] \qquad Hypothesis \\
A2: \neg (\neg \phi[a/x]) \qquad U.I \\
A3: \neg (\neg \phi[a/x]) \implies \phi[a/x] \qquad Theorem \\
A4: \phi[a/x] \qquad M.P(A2, A3) \\
A5: \exists x \phi \qquad E.G \\
A6: \neg (\forall x) \neg \phi \implies (\exists x) \phi \qquad D.T \quad A1-A5$

The theorem at A3 is one I proved in Hilbert System.

Is this proof good? Or it makes absolutely no sense, I have a lot of doubts in A2 and A5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A2 is, as you feared, incorrect.  You are basically instantiating a universal that is part of a larger statement, and you cannot do that. To see why not, let's take $\neg \forall x \phi(x)$. So this means that not everything has property $\phi$, and that means that there is something that does not have property $\phi$, ... But we don't know wat that object is. So, if I try to infer $\neg \phi(a)$, I may be inferring something that is not the case, since it is possible that $a$ *does* have property $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my doubts about A2.  So I can't instantiate, the thing that inferred from your answer is that I need to use by definition that $\neg (\forall x) \phi \quad equals \quad (\exists x) \neg \phi $ and then apply that to my problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JoseCustodio If in your system the $\forall x$is merely shorthand for $\neg \exists x \neg$, then you could try something like that, but given that you used UI in your proof attempt, it must be the case that you have a UI rule, which means that $\forall$ is not just shorthand. So, no, you cannot just apply the quantifier negation laws here... Indeed, your whole exercise is to *derive* a law like that.

Comment: You're right $\forall x $ is not a shorthand in my system, gonna think more about it, thanks for the answer.